# Known_Hosts File

Tags: networking, ssh, known-hosts

I have a couple of Raspberry Pis connected to an HP Windows 10 computer via an Ethernet LAN. When I ssh to either of the Pis from the HP I get the standard "ECDSA host key" warning. But the first two lines of the Known_Hosts file on the HP are:

Host 192.168.86.58

StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new

Not only are several keys in the file apparently
wrong but 192.168.86.58 isn't even the IP address of the HP! In fact, that address doesn't match anything on my lan!

If I delete all the entries in the file and just leave it blank, will W10 rebuild it as I log into the various machines on my lan?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're confusing the purpose and format of two different files.

`~/.ssh/known_hosts` is just a list of hostnames and their matching keys. No configuration syntax.
`-/.ssh/config` is your ssh client config, which can contain configuration syntax like "Host" stanzas and `StrictHostKeyChecking`.

It seems at some point you managed to get some config file syntax into your known_hosts file accidentally.

Yes, if you delete your known_hosts file, it will get recreated and repopulated as you ssh to devices and tell ssh to accept and remember the host keys.

Comment: There was no config file in ~/.ssh/, only the known_hosts file. But I used your hint to delete the contents of known_hosts and rebooted the W10 machine. Then as I ssh'd into each Raspberry Pi that file was populated and that solved the warning I was getting.

Thanks for your help.